# Powershell using convertto-json and calling curl doesn't like spaces in fields

Tags: json, powershell, curl

I'm using the external curl command downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/

I'm currently trying to get the curl command to write some information to elasticsearch which is running locally on my machine

I'm running the information through convertto-json to ensure that the data is formatted correctly before passing it to the external curl command

The problem I have is that any fields with a space in are immediately chucked out by curl with an unexpected end-of-input error, removing the space in the field data allows it to go in fine.

```
    $curlExe = "h:\powershell\esb\elastic\curl\curl.exe"

    function global:elasticcall ([string] $elasticdata)
    {
        $elasticoutput = "h:\powershell\esb\elastic\elastic.txt"
        $elastichost="http://localhost:9200/newtest4/filecopy/?pretty"
        $elasticheader="content-type: application/json"
        $elamethod="POST"
        $jsonelasticdata = $elasticdata | ConvertTo-Json -Compress 

        $curlargs = $elastichost,
                    '-X',$elamethod,
                    '-d',$jsonelasticdata,
                    '-H',$elasticheader

        write-host "Curl arguments in the entire string : " $curlargs
              
        & $curlexe @curlargs

        $elasticdata | Out-File $elasticoutput -Append

    }

$timereceived="randomness"
$timesentconv="randomness2"
$name="testingspaces.txt"
$curlstatus=0
$elasticbody = '{"timereceived":"' + $timereceived + '","timesent":"' + $timesentconv + '","Filename":"' + $name + '","Status":"' + $curlstatus + '"}'

elasticcall $elasticbody
```

Changing the variable $name to "testing spaces.txt" generates the error.

Comment: Why don't you use `Invoke-RestMethod`?

Comment: because invoke-restmethod is not available on the server this is running on, the powershell version is too low

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking your current string `$elasticbody` which you already manually attempted to format to json.

```
$timereceived = "randomness"
$timesentconv = "randomness2"
$name = "testing spaces.txt"
$curlstatus = 0
$elasticbody = '{"timereceived":"' + $timereceived + '","timesent":"' + $timesentconv + '","Filename":"' + $name + '","Status":"' + $curlstatus + '"}'
$elasticbody | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

This returns the following which you can see has no quotes around the filename and the string itself is wrapped in quotes.

Result: `"\"timereceived\":\"randomness\",\"timesent\":\"randomness2\",\"Filename\":\"testing spaces.txt\",\"Status\":\"0\"}"`

You should attempt to do something list this:

```
$GLOBAL:curlExe = "h:\powershell\esb\elastic\curl\curl.exe"

function global:elasticcall {
    param (
        $timereceived,
        $timesentconv,
        $name,
        $curlstatus,
        $elasticoutput = "h:\powershell\esb\elastic\elastic.txt",
        $elastichost = "http://localhost:9200/newtest4/filecopy/?pretty",
        $elasticheader = "content-type: application/json",
        $elamethod = "POST"
    )

    $elasticdata = @{
        timereceived = $timereceived
        timesent     = $timesentconv
        Filename     = $name
        Status       = $curlstatus
    }
    
    $jsonelasticdata = $elasticdata | ConvertTo-Json -Compress 

    $curlargs = $elastichost,
    '-X', $elamethod,
    '-d', $jsonelasticdata,
    '-H', $elasticheader

    write-host "Curl arguments in the entire string : " $curlargs

    & $curlexe @curlargs

    $elasticdata | Out-File $elasticoutput -Append

}

global:elasticcall -timereceived 'randomness' -timesentconv 'randomness2' -name 'testing spaces.txt' -curlstatus 0
```

You accept your variables as parameters and format them using the `ConvertTo-Json` inside the function. It should handle the spaces in your string properly.

Comment: thank you for this, i'm new to json and this has helped a lot